# "SIGSEGV on thread" error

Tags: c

I'm getting the error "SIGSEGV on thread". How I can fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int n[10], n2[10], num, nun, i=10, j=10, sv=0, on, res[4][20], opc[4][20];
main(){
    printf("Insert the 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    sv = num;
    while (num != 0)
{
        n[i] = num%10;
        num = num/10; 
        i--;
}
    num = sv;
    printf("Insert the 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d", &nun);
    sv = nun;
    while (nun != 0)
    {
        n2[j] = nun%10;
        nun = nun/10; 
        j--;
    }
    nun = sv;
    printf("Select an operation (1=addition; 2=subtraction; 3=multiplication; 4=division): ");
    scanf("%d", &on);
    while((on>4)||(on<0)){
        printf("Try again: ");
        scanf("%d", &on);
    }
    for (j=1; j<=8; j++){
        for (i=20; i>=1; i--){
            opc[j][i]=0;
        }
    }
    if (on==1)
    {
        for (i=10; i>=1; i++)
        {
            if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) <= 9)
            {
                opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i]);
            }
            if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) > 9)
            {
                opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i])%10;
                opc[1][9+i] += (n[i] + n2[i])/10;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Coming soon :)");
    }   
}
```

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2)  honor the printed page right margin (usually column 72 or 80.  3) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line..  4) insert appropriate horizontal space: inside parens, inside braces, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators 5) variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` or better, both

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: the code contains several 'magic' numbers.  I.E. 4, 10, 20.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names through out the code.

Comment: the function `main()` only has a couple of valid signatures.  All the valid signatures (regardless of what Visual Studio will allow) have a return type of `int`

Answer (score 2):

n[10] is not a valid subscript in the first loop for an array of size 10. The last valid subscript is one less than the size of the array (so 0 - 9). You would start at n[9] (not 10) and decrement down to n[0], so change n and j to 9:

```
n = 9;
j = 9;
```

The same goes for your 2d arrays. The last valid subscript for each dimension is one less than the sizes (rows/columns). opc[8][20] is not a valid subscript, which is what your for loops will try accessing.

Comment: LOL i forgot that, thanks, so this is the reason for the error?

Comment: Most likely. I'd suggest looking over arrays in C.